Does Windows request a reboot even if I suppress it for bundled exe installers?
We build our installer with WiX v3. We bundle several MSI and EXE files. One of those is itself a bundle installer which is installed using /quiet.
The problem now is that it sometimes simply reboots during the installation process leaving our installation routine incomplete.
That EXE has a switch /norestart. Now I wonder: What if I use that? Will the user be prompted to reboot at the end of our own bundle installation if necessary or will it suppress reboots completely?
Does anyone know how Windows Installer behaves here? And can you point me to where it is documented?

An educated guess: Try to set ExePackage attribute Protocol="burn". This example uses this attribute value when installing VC redist (which itself is based on Burn), so I'd assume it also handles the exit code from Burn that indicates a reboot: https://gist.github.com/nathancorvussolis/557d1c4faccd5c83d88be606c60430d0
